# What could cause a PD (access point) to not detect / pull power from a PSE (switch)?

Tags: ubiquiti, power-over-ethernet, tp-link

I've got a PD (Powered Device : [Ubiquity AirCube ISP](https://store.ui.com/collections/operator-airmax-devices/products/aircube-isp) access point) and a PSE (Power Sourcing Equipment : [TP-Link TL-SG1005P](https://www.tp-link.com/us/business-networking/unmanaged-switch/tl-sg1005p/) switch).

My understanding is that there are two ways of supplying power : A and B. The PSE (switch) in this case supports A. It is also my understanding that for a PD (access point) to be compliant, it needs to support both A and B. So in other words, the PSE controls which one to use.

> At present, all of TP-Link’s PoE switches are standard PSE and designed based on the Alternative A and the line pair 1/2 is passive pole while the line pair 3/6 is the positive pole.
>
> https://www.tp-link.com/no/support/faq/1003/

> The PSE, not the PD, decides whether power mode A or B shall be used. PDs that implement only mode A or mode B are disallowed by the standard.
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_over_Ethernet

I'm connecting the PD directly into the PSE using a CAT5e cable. The cable goes from port 1 on the PSE to the 24v PoE IN port on the PD.

The PD does not indicate power, so either I'm doing something wrong or the equipment is not compatible.

Have I missed anything with regards to how PoE devices work?

[image]

Comment: There is multiple standards of PoE IEEE 802.3af , at , bt, and also non standards. The standards are AFAIK 48V.

Can you update with exact model number? "PoE Out Controllable 24V PoE Out (4, 5+, 7, 8-) on WAN Port"

Comment: @NiKiZe added links for the products in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> from port 1 on the PSE to the 24v PoE IN port on the PD

There's the problem. Apparently, the Aircube ISP uses a proprietary "PoE" variant as indicated by the **24V** designation. IEEE PoE is 54/48V generally.

Ubiquiti is notorious for using various "PoE" variants. If they don't say *802.3af, 802.3at, 802.3bt* anywhere, it's likely not compatible with any other vendor's device.

The PoE from the switch isn't of any use here, sadly. You'll need to put a compatible Ubiquiti 24V injector between switch and the Aircube.

Comment: I naively assumed that PoE advertised devices from known brands would adhere to standards, but wrongly assumed so. I'll power the devices over USB instead then; the required additional equipment from Ubiquity is much more expensive than USB chargers. Thanks!